# How to replace a character in a string?

Tags: string, replace, str-replace

The question is, that if i have a string, i.e:

```
"--Julius.",
```

and I want replace "-" and ".". How i can get it?

Finally, I get:

```
"Julius"
```

Comment: Which language are you using Bro Alberto?

Answer (score 0):

This question have an easy solution. You only do the next:

```
word="--Julius."
word.replace("--", "")
word.replace(".", "")
print(word)
```

Output:

```
"Julius"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is specific for the JavaScript.:

```
var str ='--Julius.';
str = str.replace(/[-.]/g, function(m) { return {'-':'','.':''}[m]; }); 
console.log(s);
```

We can use the `.replace(oldvalue, newvalue)` function and replace multiple characters in a string in the similar manner:

```
var str ='--Julius.';
str = str.replace(/[-.]/g, ''); 
console.log(str);
```

We could use this instead to replace all the character with the same character.